# Does this breaker panel have too many circuits in it?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Does this breaker panel have too many poles in it?
[image: panel label]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Number of circuits

Yes it does.  The panel plainly indicates it is a Class CTL panel.

[image]

That means it complies with CTL rules, which limit the number of possible breaker spaces to 40/42.  (42 because it's a multiple of 6, relevant to 3-phase panels). This panel is certified to the number of circuits listed on the diagram, which is 40.

[image]

When CTL came out, UL rules required a "reject feature" to assure tandems won't be allowed where they do not belong. However they still needed to make non-CTL tandems to support older panels. GE did the reject feature in a very beautiful way; everyone else "notched" their bus stabs on tandem-approved spaces so a CTL breaker would reject on a non-notched stab.  *That meant non-CTL tandems would work in CTL panels; they're excluded by not being on the approved list.*

[image]

Compare to your tandems. Not on the list.

We've already had a conversation about the Square D and BRyant/Eaton breakers being aliens that don't belong here. Add to that list ALL the tandems, they either mutilated a CTL tandem, or installed non-CTL tandems anyway. Or they are non-Siemens-family tandems.

Meanwhile, over in Eaton land, Eaton applied to UL for permission to stop making CTL tandems, and allow non-CTL tandems in all legacy Eaton panels.  UL said yes.  Siemens hasn't asked yet.  So I don't quite know how to feel about this tandem business.

### Loads in the panel

Sweet Jamie butter of the western cat.   I don't know what to say here. This panel is BONKERS.

On one hand: **NO. Just NO.**  You have twelve 240V breakers which are already blowing out your Load Calculation, *and then on top of that you have a 125A feeder powering Justin Beiber alone knows what else*.  This just does not work at any level, don't even bother crunching the numbers because they're made of NOPE.

> I’ve got a 60A breaker feeding a subpanel for a heat pump and water pump. I noticed that when the heat pump starts, there’s a buzzing from the panel & dimming of lights.

**Now we know why!**

On the other hand, my all-gas winter cottage has 120V/30A *service* and the whole cottage runs on 2 breakers.  Under modern rules, it would need at least *twelve* and it could have 30 if we put each outlet on a breaker. **And the house wouldn't draw one watt more than it does presently** if we did.  So SMH I don't know. If most of these 30-40A 240V breakers are powering *like one, 1000W baseboard heater*, and each of these 15-20A tandems is powering 1 bedroom plug, maybe it just needs reorganizing.

So yeah. Maybe run a NEC 220.82 Load Calculation and see what you're really looking at here.  You'll either get an answer that you have a lot less stuff than it looks like and you can just do a cull... OR, you'll find out that you need 400A or 600A service and you can stick in multiple 40-space panels and solve your space problem while you're at it. Siemens makes fine panels and they'll take most of those breakers including the non-CTL tandems.  Find out who makes those GFCI breakers and get one panel that'll take them.  Make it so one panel has all the critical loads you might want to put on generator, because you can't feed 2 panels from 1 generator.

Comment: Pretty sure the 125A breaker is unused. I think it used to be for a point of use water heater that doesn’t exist anymore. I don’t think the buzzing from the panel had anything to do with the panel itself being overloaded — replacing that 60 amp breaker resolved it.

Comment: There are quite a few hardwired appliances, hence all the 240v circuits. Two 20 amp ovens, dishwasher, under-cabinet fridge, trash compactor. Two more 20 amp breakers for the tub in the main bathroom. Some of those 20amp slims really do have just one outlet in a hallway or just the doorbell transformer.

Comment: @Robin do the Load Calculation then.  It's still a lot. As for spaces, it does seem like there were a lot of unused or underused breakers in there, you may be able to free enough space to get rid of the tandems.  By the way if you want to do EV charging that *can* happen using tricks.

Comment: I’m also looking at an adu and a pool. I’ll need PG&E to bump me to 320 at least. Not clear if they can do it without digging up my underground service.

Comment: Yeah that's most likely so unless. you can consolidate/rationalize. For instance multiple cooking appliances get a favorable derate because of load diversity and can even share breakers.  Also, there's tech coming up fast to help you get more out of a service than was ever possible. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVLLNjSLJTQ We're just now starting to figure out how to use 1990s tech to time-shift electrical loads LOL.

Comment: @RobinDavis it might be a lot cheaper to go on a 'watt diet' than to upgrade service. https://www.redwoodenergy.net/watt-diet-calculator for info on the approaches you can use to reduce power usage so that you have a chance of making the room you need for the ADU in your load calculation.

Comment: I did the load calc and it came out to 195. I'm not terribly worried about it because some of these things _never_ get used, like the spa or the steam oven.

Comment: @KMJ Maybe, not sure I can really cut out a lot. The house is entirely electric and in general I'm already using the most efficient appliances.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Lol I have to ask, are you Alec Watson?

Comment: @Brian  if you mean the Technology Connections guy, golly you'd think so since we're so much on the same page, but no... at least not *yet*. Alec gives me hope that my future time travel experiments won't go entirely wrong :)

Comment: @Robin well 195<200 pretty definitely.  I think for modest needs you're well within the realm of existing load-shed and energy management tech, certainly an EV is no problem.  For an ADU you're gonna either need something next-gen, or a service upgrade.